# Mongoose web server in Qt C++ class

Tags: c++, qt, mongoose-web-server

I'm trying to embed a webserver in a Qt C++ program. I tried many things but I get lost CMake dependency hell. The thing that worked best so far was Mongoose. This is what it looked like:

webserver.h:

```
#ifndef HTMLINTERFACEWEBSERVER_H
#define HTMLINTERFACEWEBSERVER_H

#include <QtGlobal>
#include <QObject>
#include "mongoose.h"

namespace project
{
    class WebServer : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        WebServer();
        ~WebServer();
    public slots:
        void process();
    signals:
        void finished();
        void error(QString err);
    private:
        struct mg_mgr mgr;
    };
}

#endif
```

webserver.cpp:

```
#include "webserver.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C"
{    
    static void httpeventhandler(struct mg_connection *c, int ev, void *ev_data) {
        cout << "Event:    " << ev << endl;
        if (ev == MG_EV_HTTP_REQUEST)
        {
            cout << "Response: " << ((struct http_message *) ev_data)->resp_code << endl;
//             struct mg_serve_http_opts opts;
// 
//             memset(&opts, 0, sizeof(opts));  // Reset all options to defaults
//             opts.document_root = "/path/to/the/web/files/";
// 
//             mg_serve_http(c, (struct http_message *) ev_data, opts);
//             cout << ((struct http_message *) ev_data)->body.p << endl;
        }
    }

}

namespace project {
    WebServer::WebServer()
    {}

    WebServer::~WebServer()
    {
        mg_mgr_free(&mgr);
    }

    void WebServer::process()
    {
        struct mg_connection *c;

        mg_mgr_init(&mgr, NULL);
        c = mg_bind(&mgr, "8880", httpeventhandler);
        while (true) {
            mg_mgr_poll(&mgr, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

The body of the handler is commented out because I never got to it. All the values of the callback seem to be bogus. It looks like the callback only gets uninitialized values. This is a sample output: https://pastebin.com/8fxxAFBn It also looks like loading the page calls the handler three times.

I tried the sample mongoose program in pure C from the same libraries and it works.

This class it called from a QThread, but, as you can see, it shares no data with anything else, so that should not affect anything.

The code runs, but the values of `ev` don't make any sense. They're certainly not the expected values. They're generally `0` or some low value `1` or a bit higher if I'm trying to load a page. It should be `100`. If I force the `if` statement to be true, checking the `ev_data` struct can crash the program.

Again: my guess is that the callback handler gets uninitialized values. I'm not just sure how that's possible. I tried passing it as `httpeventhandler` as the example says and as `&httpeventhandler` as I would have guessed. It does not make a difference. Replacing `cout` with `printf` made no difference.

I can send a response with `mg_send_header` and `mg_printf` without a problem. It's just *getting* data *into* the handler that's problematic. Unfortunately, I sort of need to do that...

Comment: I guess you forgot to call `mg_set_protocol_http_websocket(c);` in your `WebServer::process()` function to attach a built-in HTTP handler.

Comment: But I'm not using websockets. I thought it was not needed for pure HTTP, only for websockets. Let me add it and look again.

Comment: That was it! I have just spent literally hours on this! Actually the main example calls this function and does not use websockets. I should have paid closer attention.